# Custom Alexa skill to write to unique dynamoDB

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I currently have a custom Alexa skill that is live. 
The skill writes and reads from a dynamoDB table but I want each user to have their own unique table. 
Right now all users data gets inputted and read from one single table that is connected to the skill. 
Is there a way for a new user to automatically create a new unique dynamoDB table when the user launches and uses the skill so that each user can only access their own data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you would want each user to have their own exclusive DynamoDB table, but I'll leave that up to you. The use-case you mention should be possible, but note that the [limit on the number of DDB tables is 256 per region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-tables). Refer to the points below:

1. In the Lambda function's input event invoked from Alexa, the "[userId](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#request-body-syntax)" parameter can be used to identify each user uniquely. Note: Normally, disabling and re-enabling a skill generates a new identifier.
2. Using the `userId` check if a DDB table with the same name exists, if not create a table and continue. If the complete `userId` cannot be set as the DDB table name, you could use [tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TagResource.html).

Comment: I would have to 2nd the you do not want a table per user. Use the userId as the key for your lookup. You could go further and require other elements for account linking or data collected in the skill like a PIN to verify a customer, but unique tables seems like it may not be the choice you want. Single table (or multi tables per skill) multi-tenant is the way to go here.

Comment: Thank you so much! I realized shortly after posting this question that each user should just have their unique userID and that should do. Currently working on that but I'm having trouble.